# Results in view page having multiple duplicate result

Tags: views

I am having a gallery view page taken from a content type which is displaying the results based on relationship and contextual filters. I am getting multiple fields of a node that seem to be duplicates, even though I have checked the reduce duplicate check box in contextual filter field.
Anyone can help on this issues to get perfect value.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Drupal/Views are you using?
In Views v7.x-3.x you can use [hook_views_pre_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) in your template.php file or in a module to filter duplicate results like this:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  $used_nids = array();
  $new_view_result = array();

  if ($view->name == 'YOURVIEWNAME') {
    foreach ($view->result as $row) {
        if (!in_array($row->nid, $used_nids)) {
          $new_view_result[] = $row;
          $used_nids[] = $row->nid;
        }
    }

    $view->result = $new_view_result;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 Even though it's not 100% rational, in the sense that you fetch all the data and then filter them instead of modifying the query, it is the only approach that worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit your view and expand "Advanced" section. In "Other" subsection choose "Query settings" and check "Distinct" -  that's all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply eugene ..the problem is in contextual filter added two more fiters.. anyhow your info is usefull for further issues.

Answer (score 0):

Only problem with [hook_views_pre_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) is that you're loosing related field values.
For example if node contains multiple value referenced field you're left with only one.
I have modified solution given by [hachesilva](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/14132/hachesilva) slightly so you can access all values in fields array:

`function YOURTHEMENAME_views_pre_render(&$view) {`

```
$used_nids = array();
$new_view_result = array();

if ($view->name == 'YOURVIEWNAME' && $view->current_display == 'YOURDISPLAYID') {
  foreach ($view->result as $row) {
    if (!in_array($row->nid, $used_nids)) {
      $new_view_result[$row->nid] = $row;
      $used_nids[] = $row->nid;
    } else {
      $new_view_result[$row->nid]->YOURFIELDNAME[] = $row->YOURFIELDNAME[0]; 
    }
  }
  $view->result = $new_view_result;
}
```

}

Use `dpm($row);` to check avalible fields name. In my case `field_author` is named `field_field_author`.
Of course You don't have to check 
`$view->current_display == 'YOURDISPLAYID'`