# Results in view page with search api having multiple duplicate result

Tags: 7, views

I am in a dilly of a pickle.
I have a view that returns indexed content types.
The problem is that the view is returning multiple instances of the same content.
All of these are indexed nodes.

I read about someone else having the same problem here: 
[Results in view page having multiple duplicate result](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39280/results-in-view-page-having-multiple-duplicate-result)
They say you can use
hook_views_pre_render() in your template.php file
to filter the extra content types out of your view.

Specifically the article said to

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  $used_nids = array();
  $new_view_result = array();

  if ($view->name == 'YOURVIEWNAME') {
    foreach ($view->result as $row) {
        if (!in_array($row->nid, $used_nids)) {
          $new_view_result[] = $row;
          $used_nids[] = $row->nid;
        }
    }

    $view->result = $new_view_result;
  }
}
```

This did not work for me. There was no $row->nid property. I think this is because they are using regular nodes and I am using indexed nodes.

Here is an example of my "$row printed out. (from $row above)

```
object(stdClass)[489]
      public 'entity' => int 4
      public '_entity_properties' => 
        array (size=2)
          'search_api_relevance' => string '1' (length=1)
          'search_api_excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
```

I altered this to try and filter by the property on "$row" called entity, which holds the id of the indexed item.

```
function BootstrapBlocks_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  $used_nids = array();
  $new_view_result = array();

  if ($view->name == 'search_the_mangroves') {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($view->result as $row) {

        if (!in_array($row->entity, $used_nids)) {

          $new_view_result[$count] = $row;

          $used_nids[$count] = $row->entity;
          $count++;
        }
    }

    $view->result = $new_view_result;
  }
}
```

Indeed this does filter out the extra content.  I know this because in template.php I printed it out to be sure, but when I set the view to use the new content
ie:  $view->result = $new_view_result;
I get no content type back from the view.
Any idea what might be the issue?

Please help me.

Sincerely,

David Pugh

PS: if you need any more info, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue.
Turns out the filter TEMPLATE_views_pre_render function I programmed in was working, the problem was in the template it's self. I had tried to solve this problem on the template before trying this issue. 
Before I was trying to only allow $row 1 to return, which didn't solve my problem.
I then tried the _views_pre_render function, and saw that it was filtering but my view was not showing any data.
That is because only one row was being returned due to the _views_pre_render function, but the only row being returned was row #0, and in the template below I was specifying to only show row 1.

So, in conclusion, if you have views with search api and find that

```
<div class="row-fluid container-folio">

        <div class="thumbnails">
        <?php $lastItem = 0;?>
            <?php foreach ($rows as $row_number => $columns): ?>    
                <?php if($row_number == 1):?>
                <?php $array = array();?>
                <?php foreach ($columns as $column_number => $item): ?>

                    <?php if($item != null && $item != "" && strlen($item) != $lastItem):?>
                        <div class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail2">                                                                
                                <?php print $item?>                                 
                            </div>                  
                        </div>
                        <?php $lastItem = strlen($item) ?>
                    <?php endif ?>


                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif ?>  
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So, in conclusion, if you have views with search api and find that the solution listed [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39280/results-in-view-page-having-multiple-duplicate-result),
Does not work for you, then your data returned to the _views_pre_render function is probably different due to your search api, and you should follow my BootstrapBlocks_views_pre_render function above, and you should be filtering out the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found that for the Search API I had set under "Use As" Search keys

I changed this to Search filter and the duplication problem went away.
This seems like a bug because using the search string as a key (breaking up the words and searching with each independently) should not have caused a duplication issue.