# Any kind of sorting gives duplicate results in Views (Search API)

Tags: 7, views, search

**Problem**

My view based on Search API is giving me duplicate results. I get duplicate results if I use the following things in combination:

- A pager
- A sort of any kind. e.g. Sort by ascending integers, sort by descending select field etc.

Sometimes I get a couple duplicate results, other times entire pages are identical.

According to the [module page](https://drupal.org/project/search_api) I should be able to use view sorts on single valued indexed fields, but I can't seem to get this to work at all.

Has anyone else run into this? How did you solve it?

**Common solutions for duplicate results**

Most of the solutions I've spotted for this involve options which don't appear for Search API. They usually involve adding [aggregation or distinct filters in the Views options](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38450/drupal-7-views-how-to-remove-duplicates-causing-from-random-sort).

The possible solution [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99085/results-in-view-page-with-search-api-having-multiple-duplicate-result) fails. The problem is it searches for duplicate results only amongst the current page of the view.

i.e. if I get 60 nodes on a search with a pager of 15, this splits into 4 pages. If the duplicates are on pages 1 & 3 then they're not spotted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bleh what a horrible bug.

I solved it by re-creating the search index (and therefore the view as well).

**Why did it happen?**

I think it's possible to have certain things saved into the Search Index (possibly when it's created?) and then it's impossible to remove them without just starting afresh.

I discovered [this bug](https://drupal.org/node/2173277) while trying to debug this.

After re-creating the new index the only difference I can find between it and the original is that I can now sort by an un-related taxonomy field (see the bug). Presumably this is an indicator of something as it doesn't seem relevant, but I have no idea what.

**Second EDIT:**

Actually just re-creating the index wasn't enough to solve this problem, I then continued to find duplicates after.

Deleting and re-creating the field with a new ID however did work. I never worked out why, but I'm presuming something was corrupted.